# Serialization with third party interface implementations in ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains implementations of a third party interface. These implementations do not implement java.io.Serializable and it's not possible to make them do so. I did see that you can make the arrayList transient, but unfortunately this has no effect. When read the arrayList i get:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: progress.message.jimpl.xmessage.MultipartMessage
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
```

where

```
progress.message.jimpl.xmessage.MultipartMessage extends progress.message.jimpl.Message implements progress.message.jclient.MultipartMessage
```

and

```
progress.message.jclient.MultipartMessage extends progress.message.jclient.Message
```

which is what the ArrayList contains.

Is there any way to prevent the NotSerializableException from occuring?

Comment: Create your own wrapperclass, which has a `MultipartMessage` and implements `Serializable`. Copy all items from the `List<MultipartMessage>` to a `List<YourClass>` and write that to the stream.

Comment: The problem is that MultipartMessage is only one of the things the ArrayList can contain. It can also contain TextMessage, XmlMessage and some more.

Comment: Sadly, if you cannot access the instance fields of the third party object (which is not itself serializable), then you will not be able to make the ArrayList serializable.  The problem is compounded if the component type of your ArrayList allows for many implementations, many or all of which are not serializable.

Comment: @Manu: embedding a non-serializable object in a wrapper class, whether or not the wrapper class is serializable, will not make the non-serializable wrapped object serializable.

Comment: @scottb if it's not possible, is there a way to prevent the stacktrace from being printed? The application itself will work with this error, but the log will be full of these errors.

Comment: @PatrickvanDeudekom: yes, you should be able to catch the  `java.io.NotSerializableException` and just simply do nothing in the code block that catches the exception (see: `try-catch-finally` blocks).  Use this technique with great care and have your `try` block cover the smallest possible block of code.

Comment: The exception was not thrown at a point at which I could catch it, but i've now configured log4j to ignore the notserializable exception. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aspectj to add an interface to a class:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/aspectj-cookbook/0596006543/ch16s04.html

Comment: Looks very good. Have no idea how to use it yet, but I hope to figure it out.

Comment: OK, in case you need help drop me a note.  And don't forget the check mark if the answer helps you :-)

Comment: I haven't found out how to use this yet. Could you give me a hint on how to start?

Comment: I solved it by filtering out the exception in my log4j config. This is sufficient in this case. I'll mark your answer anyway because it could have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Subclass of `MultipartMessage` and implement `Serializable` in it as use it in the ArrayList.

```
public classs SerializableMultipartMessage extends MultipartMessage implements Serializable {

}
```

Comment: That's not possible unfortunately, because the MultipartMessage is returned from a method in another class from the third party.

Comment: In any case, this solution would work only if the client had access to the superclass instance fields and the superclass had a no-arg constructor.